# What is the distribution of a Stochastic Process after passing through a convolutional filter?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, convolution, stochastic-filtering

Let $X(t)$ be a continuous-time, mean-zero, wide-sense stationary (covariance stationary) stochastic process, and $p(t)$ be an integrable function.

> Is there a general formula for the distribution of $Y(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(s-t)p(t)dt$?

I know there are problems with the existence of these integrals, but for now let's assume $p(t)$ is nice enough so the integral exists.

So far I have learned to calculate the mean and covariance of $Y(s)$ using the Wiener–Khinchin theorem. My guess for calculating the distribution of $Y(s)$ is to use the Karhunen–Loève theorem to write $X(t)$ as summation, then see if I can integrate each term against $p(t)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is there a general formula..." No. Probably the only tractable case is Gaussian.

Comment: @zhoraster okay thanks. I was thinking of approximating the pdf computationally using a Riemann sum. For some situations it seems that calculating the pdf of the Riemann sum is tractable, so this might be as close as I can get

Comment: You should probably refine your question. If you mean "general formula" by "closed-form solution", my answer to your question is "No". It literately depends on your $X(t)$ and $p(t)$. In Gaussian case, your $Y(s)$ is Gaussian, with mean $\int_R \mathbb{E}[X(s-t)]p(t)dt$ = 0. I believe you can also derive the covaraince